# If there there is text in another ActiveX label, then show label

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to make visible a label if there is text in an ActiveX control LABEL.

I have tried different codes but nothing seems to work

```
Private Sub makeVisible()


    Set mydocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(12)
    'mydocument.Select

    With mydocument.Shapes("LabelFigure")
    'mydocument.Shapes("LabelFigure").Select

       If mydocument.Shapes("LabelFigure").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = True Then
        Label2.Visible = True


    End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it ( it's up to you to make sure that there are shapes of the correct name on the slide ).

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub makeVisible()

    ' Always Dim your variables
    ' Including Option Explicit at the top of the module
    '   will enforce this
    Dim mydocument As Slide

    ' I've changed the slide number and label names
    ' to match my test presentation/slide.
    ' Change them back to match your situation:

    Set mydocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    With mydocument.Shapes("Label1")

       If Len(.OLEFormat.Object.Caption) > 0 Then
           mydocument.Shapes("Label2").Visible = True
       End If

    End With

    End Sub
```